# How to change number of decimal places stored in a table's field ms-access 2013 VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a macro that formats my table, changes the field names and does a few other formatting operations before I push the data to a MySQL database. Now I want to be able to change the number of decimal places stored in the table to 2 numbers after the decimal. My field name is "Quantity". Is there a property I can use to set this in VBA? I have a web page that sits on the MySQL database, so I want to do all of the operations and other fixes in the Access db so that when I push the data, it is all ready to go.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run an UPDATE query like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Quantity = Round([Quantity], 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

1. There are no 2 dec digits data type in Acs. 4-fixed-digit only is Currency. If you need exactly 2 - you need to have two fields - Long for Integer part, and Byte - for decimal, I guess...
2. Please, keep in mind that **proposed Round([Quantity], 2) is
   Banking, not school (standard) rounding!**

   ? Round(12.5)
   12
   ? Round(13.5)
   14

.